# Error in joins Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

im trying to join 2 tables on rails but its becoming imposible to me.

My schema is:

```
 table "cursos"|
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  table "users",
    t.string   "name"
  end
```

user.rb:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :cursos
```

curso.rb

```
class Curso < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

  def self.search(nameProf)

          (Cursos.joins(:users).where("users.name ilike ?",  "%#{nameProf}%").all)

  end
```

its giving me this error:

> NameError in CursosController#index
>   uninitialized constant Curso::Cursos

thanks!

Comment: Your class is called `Curso` so change it to `Curso.joins(:users)...`

Comment: try to write Curso as in singular form.

Comment: i tried that and it gives me the following error: NoMethodError in CursosController#index
undefined method `call' for #<Curso::ActiveRecord_Relation:0xb61a428>

Comment: That's because you uncovered the 2nd typo. Try `Curso.joins(:user).where("users.name ilike ?",  "%#{nameProf}%").all`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def self.search(nameProf)
  joins(:users).where("users.name ILIKE ?",  "'%#{nameProf}%'")
end
```

As search is a class method you can ommit the `Curso`

Comment: ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Cursos#index
Showing 

Association named 'users' was not found on Curso; perhaps you misspelled it?
 I think the tables are not vinculated, could it be that?

Comment: It should be `joins(:user)`, singular.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Cursos.select("*").joins(:users).where("users.name ilike ?",  "%#{nameProf}%").all
```